# How to get a string which is sibling to tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

```
<strong><i class="fas fa-id-card-alt"> </i> I want this text to be copied</strong>
```

`string = bla.find("strong").string` gives None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you'll need to create a `BeautifulSoup` element:

```
bla = '<strong><i class="fas fa-id-card-alt"> </i> I want this text to be copied</strong>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(bla, 'html.parser')
```

Next, you can use `find()` passing your desired tag, in this case `<strong>`, then use `get_text()` to get your contents:

```
string = soup.find('strong').get_text()
```

The result will be:
`'  I want this text to be copied'`

You can use the String method `strip()` to... strip the whitespaces:

```
>>> string.strip()
'I want this text to be copied'
```

Comment: It also worked in bla.find('strong').i.next_sibling.string

Comment: Thanks for answer, get_text() is new for me

Comment: If it helped you, upvote it and/or mark as solved. Thanks.